# Problem with SQLite Statement

Tags: sqlite

I am having problems with the following statement.

```
SELECT * FROM favorites WHERE personID = 1 HAVING category = "Music"
```

I am trying to get all the items of Category "Music" where there is "personID" of 1.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned by SeventotheSeven, you cannot use HAVING without a GROUP BY.

From your question, I guess you really need a simple AND:

```
SELECT * FROM favorites 
WHERE personID = 1 
AND category = 'Music'
```

Please also note that SQL uses single quotes around strings, not double quotes.

Comment: Thank you very much. That makes total sense.

Answer (score 1):

HAVING has to be used with a GROUP BY clause.